# Java ordered doubly linked list with comparable

Tags: java

I'm doing a Java exercise, and I have the following class header:

```
public class OrderedDoublyLL<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements OrderedDictionary<K, V>
```

This means that my ordered doubly linked list is ordered by key automatically?

Comment: I think you are referring to this implementation https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/fct-photoprint/source/browse/trunk/src/datastructures/OrderedDoublyLL.java?r=83

Comment: If `OrderedDictionary<K, V>` was a class instead of an interface, perhaps it would automatically sort the keys.

Comment: I will make the class by myself, but thanks. When I finish I will check that website.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, to get your question answered adding some more information to it could help!

Answer (score 4):

"Automatically"?  Not just from that class header.  The class implementation would have to enforce that.  It does guarantee that the keys *can* be ordered, but not that the keys are ordered.

Comment: Thank you. So if a don't put the "K extends Comparable<K>" isn't possible to use the compareTo method to order my keys?

Comment: Though, even if it were just `<K>`, it still could be ordered if the class took a `Comparator<? super K>` (or just `Comparator<K>`) in its constructor. This is what TreeMap does, for instance: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap(java.util.Comparator)

Answer (score 2):

All it means is that `OrderedDoublyLL` implements all of the methods in `OrderedDictionary<K,V>` and the `K extends Comparable<K>` simply means that `OrderedDoublyLL` may only take objects that can be compared to each other, aka they implement `Comparable<K>`.

If `OrderedDictionary<K, V>` were an abstract class that already defined a sorting method or a regular class and `OrderedDoublyLL` extended it, then you would not necessarily need to implement a method yourself, but that is not the case.